Least Squares as a combination of functions
I'd like to get an intuition of Least Squares in scope of function decomposition. When thinking this way, I'm translating the Linear Algebra terms like inner product to a hand-wavy notion of "function similarity".
Suppose we want to represent some function $m( x)$ as a linear combination $\alpha f_{1}( x) \ +\ \beta f_{2}( x) =\alpha \ +\ \beta x$. What I need is to find the coefficients in front of the 2 basis functions.
If the bases were orthogonal, it would've been trivial - it's along the lines of how Fourier Transform is done. But my functions aren't orthogonal. In the usual formula, we transform our bases:
\begin{equation*}
\left( A^{T} A\right)^{-1} A^{T} =\begin{bmatrix}
f_{1} \cdot f_{1} & f_{1} \cdot f_{2}\\
f_{1} \cdot f_{2} & f_{2} \cdot f_{2}
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}
f_{1}\\
f_{2}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}
I kind of understand what happens in $A^{T} A$ part - we project functions on each other, which gives us the "similarity" coefficients between them. But the inversion part - this is a mystery, I can't get any intuition of what happens to those "similarity" coefficients after it.
Alone the inverse of the inner products $( f_1 \cdot f_2)^{-1}$ kind of gives us the reciprocal of the similarities, but the inverse of a matrix does more than that. And I can't wrap my head around it.

I'm quoting from an answer which I wrote on Quora. This should clear your doubts. In your case, $A=\pmatrix{f_1&f_2}$ (which isn't a real matrix per se, but it won't matter much), $x=\pmatrix{\alpha\\\beta}$ and $b=\pmatrix{m}$.

$\DeclareMathOperator{\R}{\mathbb R}$ Solving a system of linear equations is a well-known problem in linear algebra.We have an $m\times n$ real matrix $A$ and some $b\in\R^m$.
The problem is finding a vector $x\in\R^n$ s.t. $Ax=b$.
Such a problem has a solution if and only if $b\in\text{colspace}(A)$ i.e., rank of $A$ is the same as rank of the augmented matrix $(A\mid b)$.
Now what if $b\notin \text{colspace}(A)$?
There is no solution for $x$ so our best bet is find an approximate solution.
What does it mean to find an approximate solution?
We would want to minimise the least square error i.e., we shall want to find an $x_0$ such that $\lVert Ax_0-b\rVert$ is minimal. That is what the least squares problem is about.
Let's say $b_0$ is the best approximation of $b$ by elements of $\text{colspace}(A)$. Now the equation $Ax_0=b_0$ is solvable and we can solve for $x_0$.
We have $(b-b_0)\perp \text{colspace}(A)$ i.e., $\langle b-b_0, Ax\rangle=0$ for all $x\in \mathbb R^n$.
Or, $\langle A^t(b-b_0), x\rangle=0$ for all $x\in \mathbb R^n$.
Or, $A^t(b-b_0)=0$
Or, $A^t(b-Ax_0) = 0$
Or, $(A^tA)x_0 = A^tb$ (the normal equation for $x_0$)
$A^tA$ is an $n\times n$ matrix and it’s known. $A^tb\in\R^n$ is also known. If $A^tA$ is invertible, then we can find a unique least squares solution $x_0=(A^tA)^{-1}A^tb$.
Note that since $\text{rank}(A)=\text{rank}(A^tA)$, if $A$ has full column rank then $A^tA$ is invertible.

You might ask why the residual vector of our approximation is perpendicular to the space in which we're finding approximations. You may read the theory behind best approximations which I've linked or just accept this as a fact that if $w$ is the best approximation of some vector $v$ by elements of $W$ then the residual vector $(v-w)\perp W$.
In the language of projections, the best approximation $b_0$ is the orthogonal projection of $b$ onto the subspace spanned by columns of $A$.
